# Count numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Here is my method

```
private static void methodCount(int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for(int i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        int num1 = array[i];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j < array.length;j++) {
            int num2 = array[j];
            if(num1 == num2) {
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Number " + num1 + " is counted " + counter + " times!");
    }
}
```

I can`t figure out why output is changing, for example:

```
int[] array = {2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 3, 8};
methodCount(array);
```

Output is

```
Number 1 is counted 1 times!
Number 2 is counted 3 times!
Number 4 is counted 2 times!
Number 7 is counted 2 times!
Number 9 is counted 1 times!
```

And for this array

```
int[] array = {2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 9};
methodCount(array);
```

Output is

```
Number 2 is counted 2 times!
Number 4 is counted 2 times!
Number 7 is counted 2 times!
```

Last four numbers are deleted: 2, 1, 3, 8.

Arrays.sort(array) is not necessary, i know.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `i++;` in the `if`.

Comment: answer accepter! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the comparison if(num1 == num2) would perform a self comparison. That means, in one of the iterations num1 and num2 would be the exact same element in the array. And for that case an increment of 'i' is not required.

An alternative solution is as follows:

```
private static void methodCount(int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int num1 = array[i];
        int counter = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            int num2 = array[j];
            if (num1 == num2) {
                counter++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number " + num1 + " is counted " + counter + " times!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second `for` loop, inside `if(num1 == num2)` statement:

You should remove `i++;`

Even in your first try for this array `int[] array = {2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 3, 8};
methodCount(array);`
You aren't counting all numbers. ( 6?  8?).

Comment: Yes i know, just because of that i asked question :)